# JQuery xml sort by specific node value

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sorting

I have a xml file with some data and want to sort by some node value.

this is what i have:

```
var output = '';

$.ajax({
        url:'file.xml',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result) {
            $(result).find('car').each(function() {
                output += '<div class="block">';
                output += '<b>Marca</b> : '+$(this).find('marca').text()+'<br>';
                output += '<b>Modelo</b> : '+$(this).find('modelo').text()+'<br>';
                output += '<b>Equipamento</b> : ';

                var arr = [];
                $(this).find('equip').children().each(function() {
                    arr.push($(this).text());
                });
                output += arr.join(', ');

                output += '</div>'

            });

            $('body').append(output);
        }
    })
```

i want to sort by value of "marca". How can i do that?

here's my xml file:

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <marca>Seat</marca>
        <modelo>Ibiza</modelo>
        <equip>
            <equip1>Vidros Electricos</equip1>
            <equip2>Fecho Central</equip2>
            <equip3>Direcção Assistida</equip3>
        </equip>
    </car>
    <car>
        <marca>Volkswagen</marca>
        <modelo>Golf</modelo>
        <equip>
            <equip1>Vidros Electricos</equip1>
            <equip2>Fecho Central</equip2>
            <equip3>Direcção Assistida</equip3>
            <equip4>ABS</equip4>
        </equip>
    </car>
    <car>
        <marca>Honda</marca>
        <modelo>Civic</modelo>
        <equip>
            <equip1>Vidros Electricos</equip1>
            <equip2>Fecho Central</equip2>
            <equip3>Direcção Assistida</equip3>
            <equip4>ABS</equip4>
        </equip>
    </car>
    (...)
</cars>
```

In this case the order should be -> Honda -> Seat -> Volkswagen.

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort()` on a jQuery collection

```
$(result).find('car').sort(function(a,b){
      return $(a).find('marca').text() > $(b).find('marca').text()
}).each(function(){
      // output sorted collection
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hWKqp3rhTBAYhTrPfQEa?p=preview)**</kbd>